# Using reference to type parameter in callback function of C library

Tags: rust, ffi

I am writing a Rust interface to a C library that has a function with the following signature:

```c
typedef int (*callback_t)(const int *a, void *user_data);
void execute(callback_t callback);
```

What I would like is that the users of the Rust interface can pass any type `T` for `user_data` (`user_data` is not used in the C library). In other words, on the Rust side I would like:

```rust
type Callback<T> = fn(a: &mut usize, user_data: &mut T) -> usize;
```

I tried casting a user-defined Rust function of type `Callback<T>` to

```rust
extern "C" fn callback(a: *mut c_int, user_data: *mut c_void) -> c_int
```

with `as`, but that does not work. I also tried to create a wrapping closure. Both attempts did not work.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be casting function pointers between different signatures.  That's catastrophically unsafe and will blow your program up (if you're lucky).  Function pointers are **not** interchangeable, and the compiler cannot magically make them compatible.

What you're effectively doing here is taking an order written in Italian, scratching out "language = Italian", replacing it with "language = Russian", and expecting the Russian chef to understand it because, hey, it says it's in Russian!

First of all, your translation of the raw C type is probably wrong.  The first argument is `*const c_int`, not `*mut c_int`.  C does allow you to cast `const` away, but it's rarely something the other code will expect.

Secondly, you should not translate raw C pointers as safe Rust references.  If the C code calls with a null pointer, your Rust code will have undefined behaviour.  Unless the C library guarantees that both pointers are never null with a contract signed in blood and guaranteed with the programmer's first born child, don't trust it: check the pointers first.

Third, `c_int` and `usize` are not the same type.  Do not conflate them.  The correct type to use for the Rust interface is `c_int`.

So the actual C callback type in Rust is:

```
type CCallback = Option<extern "C" fn(a: *const c_int, user_data: *mut c_void) -> c_int>;
```

The `Option` is there because C function pointers can be null, in Rust they can't.

Finally, `Callback<T>` isn't marked with `extern "C"`.  Getting the calling convention exactly right is of critical importance.

The signature of any function you intend to cast to the C callback type should be *exactly* the C callback signature.  That is:

```
extern "C" fn a_callback(a: *const c_int, user_data: *mut c_void) -> c_int {
    ::std::process::abort();
}
```

Now, you *might* be able to get away with this:

```
extern "C" fn a_callback<T>(a: *const c_int, user_data: *mut T) -> c_int {
    ::std::process::abort();
}
```

And coerce `Some(a_callback)` to `CCallback`.  That said, I can't guarantee this is correct for all possible `T`.

To be safe, you should explicitly wrap all Rust callback functions in a translation function.  This is most easily done with a macro that, given the name of the Rust function, generates a C shim.

```
macro_rules! shim {
    ($c:ident => $r:ident) => {
        extern "C" fn $c(a: *const c_int, user_data: *mut c_void) -> c_int {
            if a.is_null() {
                ::std::process::abort()
            }
            if user_data.is_null() {
                ::std::process::abort()
            }
            // NOTE: You need to make *absolutely certain* that this cast
            // of user_data is valid.
            let res: i32 = $r(&*a, &mut *(user_data as *mut _));
            res as c_int
        }
    };
}

shim!(another_callback_c => another_callback);

fn another_callback(a: &c_int, user_data: &mut u8) -> i32 {
    // Do something...
    ::std::process::abort()
}
```

Comment: "C does allow you to cast const away", yes and no, allow you ok, but attempt to modify the object is undefined behavior.

Comment: "Now, you might be able to get away with this:", if we only talk about C, no `void *` and `T *` are not compatible pointer.

Comment: @Stargateur: But they should be the same size (for `Sized` types), and in these cases, `void *` is just being used as an opaque payload.

Comment: No one disallow system where pointer are not the same size, C require that all pointer to struct are compatible also enum if I remember, but `void *` is allowed to have any representation, so C require an implicit or explicit cast to void *, that also the reason why one must cast pointer with `printf("%p", (void *)p);`. But if Rust run on a system I don't think pointer would have funky representation, that why I say "if we talk only about C".

Comment: Thanks! The `const` thing was an error on my part when trying to simplify the actual API for this example. The reason why I use `usize` in my example is because I want to hide the `c_int` from the user.

Comment: @Stargateur You can cast away a `const` so long as the pointer does not actually point to constant memory `int x = 1; const int *p = &x; *(int *)p = 2; assert(x == 2);` is valid.

Comment: @yyny please, C is already unsafe enough to not do that period, https://www.viva64.com/en/w/v2567/

Comment: @Stargateur Your link is irrelevant, not only does it show a C++ specific problem, it is also completely different. There is nothing unsafe about what I'm show whether it is done in C or C++, pointer aliasing is well defined. The only thing "unsafe" about C/C++ that you have to understand how the language behaves, instead of telling the language how it should behave, as you do with Rust.